# Load HTML in QTextEdit with Image with relative Path

Tags: qt, qtextedit

With QWebKit I was able to load HTML with a baseurl:

```
// File e.g. with <img src="images/picture.jpg" />
const QByteArray oHTMLContent = oFile.readAll();
QFile oFile( rFileInfo.absoluteFilePath() );

QUrl oBaseUrl = QUrl::fromLocalFile( rFileInfo.absolutePath() + "/" );
QWebFrame* pFrame = m_pWebView->page()->mainFrame();
pFrame->setHtml( oHtmlContent, oBaseUrl );
```

Is there a way to do the same with QTextEdit? (because my images are all relative to the HTML document and not to the binary (QDir::currentPath()).

Comment: Does `QTextEdit::setHtml()` with `oFile.readAll()` as an argument work for you?

Comment: yes, but I will edit the example code to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

After long searching I found the solution in Qt's code:

```
m_pWebView->document()->setMetaInformation( QTextDocument::DocumentUrl,
                                            rFileInfo.absolutePath() + "/" );
```

Source is [qtextdocument.cpp in line 1990](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/f7b3072924fb57b3979ff4d536eb213270be1047%3asrc/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp#L1992).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your brainwave

for me (dable  ©Aznavour) 
this works on Mac and Linux 
only if "file:" is prepended.

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
  document()->setMetaInformation( QTextDocument::DocumentUrl, imagePath + "/" );
#else
  document()->setMetaInformation( QTextDocument::DocumentUrl, "file:" + imagePath + "/");
#endif
```

thanks (this works onWindows, Mac, Linux, QT 4.6.3 --> 5.3.1)